# What does escape sequence \a do and when should I use it?

Tags: string, lua, escaping

I was learning about escape sequences in Lua and I figured out what most of them do, but I can't figure out what \a does.

I'm on Windows 10. I've tried print("aaa\abbb") , but it just prints aaabbb.
Is there any actual use for this escape sequence?

Comment: I'm trying but I havent found anything yet.

Comment: Ok, so I googled it and it prints a bell code. I was confused because it didn't work for some reason in standalone lua interpreter. It worked in SciTe.

Comment: [All chars and char classes in Lua](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/98fa4afda5a157904522a52dc442440b)